# .raw file in Paraview

Tags: dataset, paraview

I have downloaded a .raw datafile that I want to view in Paraview.
The dataset I'm using is taken from:

http://volvis.org/ -> download dataset -> CT Scan of bonsaitree.

Whenever I import the dataset I do as explained here in this link:
http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats#Raw_files

Everything goes fine until I hit apply. I then get these two error messages, and the view is empty:

```
ERROR: In C:\DBD\pvs-x64\paraview\src\paraview\ParaViewCore\VTKExtensions\Rendering\vtkTexturePainter.cxx, line 295
vtkTexturePainter (00000000136105F0): Incorrect dimensionality.


Warning: In C:\DBD\pvs-x64\paraview\src\paraview\VTK\Rendering\Core\vtkRenderer.cxx, line 1030
vtkOpenGLRenderer (0000000009CF08C0): Resetting view-up since view plane normal is parallel
```

How do I get rid of these error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raw file does not have a header with information about the data inside (orientation, dimension...). You have to provide that information, and it has to be compatible with the content of the image. I tried a couple of time with the data you provided and succeeded with the following parameters:

when prompted reader: raw binary file (I just checked the file content with notepad)
data extent: 0 255 0 255 0 255 (the website says that the image is 256x256x256)
data scalar type: char (I confess that I just guessed it at the first time, a more correct way would be to multiply the data type by the number of voxels and compare it with the file dimension).